# slicing pandas dataframe encounter KeyError: 'n_tokens_content', how to locate the bad rows efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to explore this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00332/) with pandas 0.20.3 in Python 3.6.2.

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('OnlineNewsPopularity.csv')
df['n_tokens_content'][:9]
```

last line produces error

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
>   in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2441             try:
>   -> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2443             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/_libs/index.c:5280)()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20523)()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)()
>
> KeyError: 'n_tokens_content'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df['n_tokens_content'][:9]
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)    1962             return
>   self._getitem_multilevel(key)    1963         else:
>   -> 1964             return self._getitem_column(key)    1965     1966     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py
>   in _getitem_column(self, key)    1969         # get column    1970
>   if self.columns.is_unique:
>   -> 1971             return self._get_item_cache(key)    1972     1973         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
>   in _get_item_cache(self, item)    1643         res = cache.get(item)
>   1644         if res is None:
>   -> 1645             values = self._data.get(item)    1646             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)    1647
>   cache[item] = res
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
>   in get(self, item, fastpath)    3588     3589             if not
>   isnull(item):
>   -> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)    3591             else:    3592                 indexer =
>   np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
>   in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2442
>   return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2443             except KeyError:
>   -> 2444                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2445     2446
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/_libs/index.c:5280)()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>   (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20523)()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)()
>
> KeyError: 'n_tokens_content'

I think this is caused by some rows in the csv file, as this piece of code work well for other csv.

if yes, how to locate the bad rows efficiently?

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This error means there is no column called `n_tokens_content` in the dataframe you created.  You'll have to examine the dataframe (e.g., run `df.columns` or `df.head()`) to see what your column names are.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the columns using df.columns then 'n_tokens_content' has a leading space at the start.

Input: `df.columns`

Output:

```
Index(['url', ' timedelta', ' n_tokens_title', ' n_tokens_content',
   ' n_unique_tokens', ' n_non_stop_words', ' n_non_stop_unique_tokens',
   ' num_hrefs', ' num_self_hrefs', ' num_imgs', ' num_videos',
   ' average_token_length', ' num_keywords', ' data_channel_is_lifestyle',
   ' data_channel_is_entertainment', ' data_channel_is_bus',
   ' data_channel_is_socmed', ' data_channel_is_tech',
   ' data_channel_is_world', ' kw_min_min', ' kw_max_min', ' kw_avg_min',
   ' kw_min_max', ' kw_max_max', ' kw_avg_max', ' kw_min_avg',
   ' kw_max_avg', ' kw_avg_avg', ' self_reference_min_shares',
   ' self_reference_max_shares', ' self_reference_avg_sharess',
   ' weekday_is_monday', ' weekday_is_tuesday', ' weekday_is_wednesday',
   ' weekday_is_thursday', ' weekday_is_friday', ' weekday_is_saturday',
   ' weekday_is_sunday', ' is_weekend', ' LDA_00', ' LDA_01', ' LDA_02',
   ' LDA_03', ' LDA_04', ' global_subjectivity',
   ' global_sentiment_polarity', ' global_rate_positive_words',
   ' global_rate_negative_words', ' rate_positive_words',
   ' rate_negative_words', ' avg_positive_polarity',
   ' min_positive_polarity', ' max_positive_polarity',
   ' avg_negative_polarity', ' min_negative_polarity',
   ' max_negative_polarity', ' title_subjectivity',
   ' title_sentiment_polarity', ' abs_title_subjectivity',
   ' abs_title_sentiment_polarity', ' shares'],
  dtype='object')
```

Give input as: `df[' n_tokens_content'][:9]`

output:

   `0     219
   1     255
   2     211
   3     531
   4    1072
   5     370
   6     960
   7     989
   8      97`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and it has been solved: 
input:
`df.columns`
output:

```
 Index(['url', ' timedelta', ' n_tokens_title', ' n_tokens_content',
       ' n_unique_tokens', ' n_non_stop_words', ' n_non_stop_unique_tokens',
       ' num_hrefs', ' num_self_hrefs', ' num_imgs', ' num_videos',
       ' average_token_length', ' num_keywords', ' data_channel_is_lifestyle',
       ' data_channel_is_entertainment', ' data_channel_is_bus',
       ' data_channel_is_socmed', ' data_channel_is_tech',
       ' data_channel_is_world', ' kw_min_min', ' kw_max_min', ' kw_avg_min',
       ' kw_min_max', ' kw_max_max', ' kw_avg_max', ' kw_min_avg',
       ' kw_max_avg', ' kw_avg_avg', ' self_reference_min_shares',
       ' self_reference_max_shares', ' self_reference_avg_sharess',
       ' weekday_is_monday', ' weekday_is_tuesday', ' weekday_is_wednesday',
       ' weekday_is_thursday', ' weekday_is_friday', ' weekday_is_saturday',
       ' weekday_is_sunday', ' is_weekend', ' LDA_00', ' LDA_01', ' LDA_02',
       ' LDA_03', ' LDA_04', ' global_subjectivity',
       ' global_sentiment_polarity', ' global_rate_positive_words',
       ' global_rate_negative_words', ' rate_positive_words',
       ' rate_negative_words', ' avg_positive_polarity',
       ' min_positive_polarity', ' max_positive_polarity',
       ' avg_negative_polarity', ' min_negative_polarity',
       ' max_negative_polarity', ' title_subjectivity',
       ' title_sentiment_polarity', ' abs_title_subjectivity',
       ' abs_title_sentiment_polarity', ' shares'],
      dtype='object')
```

you can find that the title of the column `"n_tokens_title"` is `" n_tokens_title"`, notice the space front the n_tokens_title, and add the space in your code.